# Ordering Items by Known Parent

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have a class called `LinkedUser` which looks something like this :

```
public class LinkedUser 
{
     public int Id {get; set;}         
     public int? ParentId {get; set;}
     public string CardNumber {get; set;}
     public int RootUserId {get; set;}
}
```

Now, let's say I want retrieve all `LinkedUser`'s where `RootUserId == 1`, and I get back data that looks like this, in no particular order :

```
var linkedUserList = return new List<LinkedUser>()
{
    new LinkedUser {Id = 1, CardNumber = "546251357655", ParentId = null, RootUserId = 1},
    new LinkedUser {Id = 5869, CardNumber = "666547395503", ParentId = 1, RootUserId = 1},
    new LinkedUser {Id = 214, CardNumber = "666558432178", ParentId = 5869, RootUserId = 1},
    new LinkedUser {Id = 8957, CardNumber = "987265985430", ParentId = 214, RootUserId = 1},
    new LinkedUser {Id = 3650, CardNumber = "987653215430", ParentId = 8957, RootUserId = 1}
};
```

**My Question :**

What I would like to do is **sort** this list by descending `ParentId`'s in terms of inheritance (not just the raw integer value).

I first solved this by adding an `index` property to the class, but I feel like this could be done way more elegantly through LINQ - I just can't wrap my head around the syntax to do it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: you're missing a closing `}` for this line in your class by the way 
`public int RootUserId {get; set;` also incorrect `var linkedUserList = return new List<LinkedUser>()
{` remove the `return` key word

Comment: what do you mean by sorting in terms of inheritance?

Comment: Trying to think how to explain this... I'll always have a user with a null `ParentId`, which gives me the root user. From there, I'd like to list out each child in descending order, so by how they're inherited from the root patron down to the bottom of the chain. Does that make any sense? I'm sorry if my terminology is off...

Comment: @X3074861X, I have pasted your exact code into my console and tested the code .. I written a `1` line piece of code that will do the sorting for you using a `Lambda statement` sorts exactly what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be possible to build an actual tree?

```
var linkedUserList = return new List<LinkedUser>()
{
    new LinkedUser {Id = 1, CardNumber = "546251357655", ParentId = null, RootUserId = 1, Children = new [] {
        new LinkedUser {Id = 5869, CardNumber = "666547395503", ParentId = 1, RootUserId = 1, Children = new [] {
            new LinkedUser {Id = 214, CardNumber = "666558432178", ParentId = 5869, RootUserId = 1},
            ... etc
        }},

    }},
};
```

This puts you on a footing to manipulate each child collection individually.

So now you can walk the tree (uncompiled);

```
public void SortUser(LinkedUser user)
{
    user.Children.Sort((c1,c2) => Math.sign(c2-c1));
    foreach(var child in user.Children)
    {
        SortUser(child);
    }
}
```

Stick a 'Descendents' property on LinkedUser;

```
public IEnumrable<LinkedUser> Descendents()
{
    yield return this;
    foreach(var descendent in Children)
    {
        foreach(var result in child.Descendents())
        {
            yield return descendent;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can do;

```
var hierarchicallyOrdered = linkedUserList.SelectMany(usr => usr.Descendents()).ToList();
```

Comment: This got me going in the right direction - building the full tree with the Descendents was what I ended up with.

Comment: Good stuff! Glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LinkedUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }
    public int RootUserId { get; set; }
}

var linkedUserList =  new List<LinkedUser>()
{
    new LinkedUser {Id = 1, CardNumber = "546251357655", ParentId = null, RootUserId = 1},
    new LinkedUser {Id = 5869, CardNumber = "666547395503", ParentId = 1, RootUserId = 1},
    new LinkedUser {Id = 214, CardNumber = "666558432178", ParentId = 5869, RootUserId = 1},
    new LinkedUser {Id = 8957, CardNumber = "987265985430", ParentId = 214, RootUserId = 1},
    new LinkedUser {Id = 3650, CardNumber = "987653215430", ParentId = 8957, RootUserId = 1}
};

List<LinkedUser> sortedList = linkedUserList.OrderBy(o => o.ParentId).ToList();
```

using the debugger to inspect `linkedUserList` you will see that from `Items[0] thru item[4]` the sortedList variable

> item[0] ParentId = null
>
> item[1] ParentId = 1
>
> item[2] ParentId = 214
>
> item[3] ParentId = 5869
>
> item[4] ParentId = 8957